# Is membership by relationship charged for?

Tags: civimember, contribution-page

I've created an organisation membership and set a cost. I've also made a relationship so employees inherit that relationship. I can't find out anywhere if someone inherits that membership are they also charged?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I'm aware only the organisation is charged but the employees are able to receive the benefits of membership.  The employees don't get charged separately for that membership.

You can find more information about membership in the book:
[Defining memberships](http://gitbook.civicrm.org/membership/defining-memberships.html)

Comment: agree. the cost is only associated with the parent membership